# In Python how do I get the max value of a 'column' in a 2D array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python how do I get the max value of a 'column' in a 2D array?

I can see that trainingData has a max and min which is the max and min values of the entire 2D array but I would like the max value for each "column".

I've tried several things and this is my last attempt but it didn't seem to work:

creating it:

```
trainingData = []
```

filling it:

```
for row in csv_reader:
    trainingData.append(row)
```

converting to np

```
npTrainingData = np.array(trainingData)
```

printing it:

```
for x in range(1, 12):
    print(np.max(npTrainingData[:x]))
```

I've scoured stack overflow but nobody seems to solve this at all but have a ton of similar questions.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Have you tried specifying the optional `axis` argument when calling `max`? It would help people to answer your question if you showed some example data and the expected output.

Comment: `print(npTrainingData.max(axis=1))` without the `for` loop?

Comment: You mean print(npTrainingData.max(x))?

Comment: @roganjosh that just returns an array of values

Comment: @johncliffe how is that different than iterating?

Comment: @roganjosh I think axis `0`is what they're searching for. @johncliffe the max-function with the array as result replaces the for loop

Comment: @SpghttCd you are correct I believe. If you wanna write it in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of explicitly iterating over the elements (or sub-arrays) of an array like

```
for x in range(1, 12):
    print(np.max(npTrainingData[:x]))
```

there are numpy functions, which can be controlled regarding on which axis they are applied. E.g. `np.max`:

```
np.max(npTrainingData, 0)
```

or equivalently

```
npTrainingData.max(0)
```

where the `0` here is the `axis` parameter, which can be 0 or 1 for 2D-arrays.
When left blank, the maximum of the flattened array, i.e. a single value for the whole dataset is returned.